# How to get specific element Count in XML or XElement variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

Consider this XML:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

I declare a `XElement` variable and create the XML assigning it to that. How I can get count of `ID` elements in this XML variable in C#?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Prerequisite:** in order to use `.Count()` you need to import the namespace `System.Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You can filter the descendant elements using the [`Descendants` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) with the name "ID", then count the results:

```
int count = xml.Descendants("ID").Count();
```

Be aware that `Descendants` looks through all levels. If you had an element other than `Person` that also had an `ID` child element, you would want to be more specific. In that case, to count `ID` child elements that belong to `Person` elements, you would use:

```
int count = xml.Elements("Person")
               .Elements("ID")
               .Count();
```

Comment: If you don't use `Elemets("Employees")` it returns 0 :-?

Comment: @Nima based on your sample input `Employees` is the root node, and if you're using an `XElement` there's no need for `Elements("Employee")` to be part of the query. If it isn't the root element, then you can either include it, or use `xml.Descendants("Person").Elements("ID").Count()` instead, thereby avoiding the need to walk the XML element by element.

Comment: Is this answer still current? As far as I can tell, `Descendants()`and `Elements()` both return an `IEnumerable`, which doesn't seem to have a `Count()`method. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.Load(XmlPath);
var totalItems = xmldoc.SelectNodes(
         "/root/node/LastName/").Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt = element.Descendants("ID").Count();
```