# SilverLight XElement's Nodes count

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have one `XElement` object where in there are `Nodes` present inside that object, i want to get the `Nodes` count **without iterating** over all the elements using `IEnumarable`.

How do i do this?

**Note:** [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764510/how-to-get-specific-element-count-in-xml-or-xelement-variable) is not applicable in my case because no support for`.Count` in **SilverLight**

Comment: that `Count` is IEnumerable's method not XElement's.

Comment: how can you say that `.Count()` is not supported? how you tried to use `.Count()`?

Comment: @L.B I know its IEnumerable's method thats why i was calling XElement's Nodes method which returns IEnumerable.

Comment: @har07 I have tried but its not present. :(

Comment: @Rinkalkumar have you included `using System.Linq?`

Comment: @L.B ...and add a reference to System.Xml.Linq

Comment: @Jehof He is already using `XElement`. So It must be present.

Comment: @L.B can you answer the same so that i can accept, adding using System.Linq worked for me. i hate microsoft....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count` is an extension method of  `Enumerable` class. To be able to use it, you should add

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Infact using linq you can count the number of nodes like this,

```
 doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("YourXml");
 doc.Root.Descendants().Count(d => (string)d.Attribute("attName") == "value");
```