# Counting number of element in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

First of all I referred this post [How to get specific element Count in XML or XElement variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764510/how-to-get-specific-element-count-in-xml-or-xelement-variable) and could not solve the problem which i was facing so i am writing this. 
The part of the xml is given as below I want to count the number of element that is number of occurance scalarvariable in modelvariables node as shown below

```
<ModelVariables>
 <ScalarVariable name="x" valueReference="0" description="the only state"causality="local" variability="continuous" initial="exact">
    <Real start="1"/>
 </ScalarVariable>
 <ScalarVariable name="der(x)" valueReference="1" causality="local" variability="continuous"        initial="calculated">
    <Real derivative="1"/>
 </ScalarVariable>
 <ScalarVariable name="k" valueReference="2" causality="parameter" variability="fixed" initial="exact">
    <Real start="1"/>
 </ScalarVariable>
</ModelVariables>
```

I have defined as

> XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
>               doc.Load(@"W:\Prajwal\FMU_EXTRACT\modelDescription.xml");

and i have created nodelist as

> XmlNodeList nodeList =
>   (XmlNodeList)doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ModelVariables/ScalarVariable");

I need to get the number of occurnace of the **scalarvariable**

Comment: Doesn't nodeList.Count() work?

Comment: You can also put `count()` in the XPath expression, if you don't actually need the `ScalarVariable` nodes themselves: `count(//ModelVariables/ScalarVariable)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) here:-

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"W:\Prajwal\FMU_EXTRACT\modelDescription.xml");
int ScalarVariableCount = doc.Root.Element("ModelVariables")
                                  .Elements("ScalarVariable").Count();
```

Comment: `ModelVariables` is not your root node? and what error BTW?

Comment: ModelVariables is not root

Comment: the error is the System.xml.xmlDocument doesn't contain definition of Root

Comment: the root node is **fmiDescription** in that **ModelVariables** is there

Comment: @Prajwal - Please check my update, it's `XDocument` and if you have `ModelVariables` as direct child of `fmiDescription ` then this will give correct result.