# Is there a well-defined way to measure size and/or complexity of XML files?

Tags: java, android, xml, metrics, code-complexity

Usually LOC is one of widely used metrics for measuring source code of programs. It works perfectly for measuring size of Java or C code.
However, in one of our current research projects, we need to measure the size of code in XML files. LOC seems not a good fit for this purpose, due to the flexibility of XML format.

I was wondering whether there is a good way to measure size or complexity of XML code. I have searched online, and most published research work focus on defining complexity of XML schema, DTD, instead of XML files. Such as: *[Metrics for XML Document Collections](http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/users/azhang/disc/springer/0558/papers/2490/24900015.pdf)*

I also find that there are tools/libraries can count/list nodes or elements based on different tag names. Such as:
*[Counting number of element in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32141980/290085)*
and *[Simplest way to get XML node count](https://superuser.com/q/708520/254522)*

However, our research does not care about names of tags or elements. We only need a well-defined metric to measure size or complexity of code in XML files, especially Android layout files and AndroidManifest.xml files.

Comment: There many "well-defined" ways to measure anything, but without describing the characteristic you wish to quantify, it's impossible to identify a suitable metric.

Comment: Thanks. I want to quantify the size and/or complexity of an xml file.

Comment: @dmark That's not an answer. It's like asking "How can I measure the spongificity of airline passengers", and when someone asks what you want to quantify, you respond that you want to quantify their spongificity. If you don't know what you want to measure, how can someone else know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Well-defined ways to measure XML files

### Size

- XML file byte count
- Text content character count
- {Element|Attribute|[DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) node} count
- Aggregates of above measures

### Complexity

- Unique {element|attribute} name count
- Maximum or average {depth|width} of element tree hierarchy
- [Directed Acyclic Graph measures](https://logic.rwth-aachen.de/~rabinovich/diplomarbeit.pdf) for ID/IDREF DAG structures
- Size of smallest schema that would validate the XML

  - Limited to a specific schema standard {XSD|DTD|RelaxNG|...}
  - Limited to a specific schema feature subset (eg: no `xsd:any`, ...)
- [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of XML file as a string

Comment: I have a further question: some Elements may contain other Elements, e.g., <bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>  Then, how to count them?

Comment: 1, 2, 3...   Can't be more specific until you state your purpose.

Comment: <title>Harry Potter</title> can be one element, but <book> ... </book> that encloses it can be one as well, right? When we count, should we only consider lowest level elements that don't contain any others, or also count those higher level ones, such as "book" here? It seems more complicated if we count them regardless their different levels.

Comment: So in the above example, there are 2 title elements, 2 author elements, 2 year elements, 2 price elements at the lowest level, and 2 book elements at the mid-level, and 1 bookstore element. Am I correct? Or, should I only count 2+2+2+2 at the lowest level?

Comment: You're chasing your tail in metric land when you should be deciding the *purpose* of the metric first.   We cannot possibly evaluate the value of any metric without knowing your goal for measuring.

Comment: yes, I can sort of feel it... I need to compare xml files in terms of their size. For example, a large Android app may include a "big" AndroidManifest.xml, while a small toy app usually has a tiny one. But I need a ''number'' to show one is big, another is small. We wanted to use LOC, but same XML file can have different LOC because of its flexible format. So LOC doesn't seem to be a good fit here. This is my purpose: to have a number to show its size.