# How to parse this XML to get the count on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, xml-parsing

I need a help to parse the below XML, What I wanted to do is the count of the entry id, below XML has 5 for entry id's. So What code should I write on C# to get the count from this XML? Thanks in advance

```
<entry_list version="1.0">
<entry id="cipher[1]">...</entry>
<entry id="cipher[2]">...</entry>
<entry id="cypher">...</entry>
<entry id="substitution cipher">...</entry>
<entry id="transposition cipher">...</entry>
</entry_list>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I got this result from an api, so i tried like this

Comment: string wordres = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Retrive the values from the response

        XmlDocument wordxml = new XmlDocument();

        wordxml.LoadXml(wordres);
        XmlNode root = wordxml.DocumentElement;

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764510/how-to-get-specific-element-count-in-xml-or-xelement-variable

Comment: @iamal For additions like that, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49809695/edit), that is more clear than having it scattered across comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of element in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141980/counting-number-of-element-in-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"FileToLoad.xml");

var count = xdoc.Descendants("entry").Count(); // 5
```

Comment: Its showing that xmldocument doesn't contains a method for Descendants and is showing as error

Comment: you need those two usings: using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: added those, still its not sorted out

Comment: I suspect you're referring to `XmlDocument`, rather than `XDocument` as per Daniel's code.